# PHP error logging does not work via .htaccess

Tags: php, logging

I need to have all PHP errors logged to a file on my centOS box. I think I'm doing everything I'm supposed to. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag log_errors On
php_flag error_log /var/www/vhosts/hostname/logs/fo_errors.log
```

- In my php.ini, I have error_reporting=E_ALL set.
- Apache does parse .htaccess
- `/var/www/vhosts/hostname/logs/fo_errors.log` has owner set to `apache:apache` and has write permissions.

I'm out of ideas.. can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want to use `php_value` not `php_flag` when you set the log path. `php_flag` is only used for setting boolean configuration properties.

```
php_flag display_errors off 
php_flag log_errors On 
php_value error_log /var/www/vhosts/hostname/logs/fo_errors.log
```

Comment: Doh-uh! I needed a second pair of eyes to see that one. Thanks Tom.

Comment: Can someone edit this answer and add the corrected htaccess? This could be useful for others.

Answer (score 23):

Try adding the following test page to your web root:

```
<?php
// debug.php
echo "<pre>";
echo "log_errors = [", ini_get('log_errors'), "]\n";
echo "error_log = [", ini_get('error_log'), "]\n";
echo "writeable? ", is_writable(ini_get('error_log')) ? 'Yes' : 'No', "\n";
echo "</pre>";
error_log("Test from error_log()");
user_error("Test error from user_error()");
```

Browse to `/debug.php` and you should see the following output:

```
log_errors = [1]
error_log = [/var/www/vhosts//logs/fo_errors.log]
Writeable? Yes
```

You should also see two messages appear in your log file each time you visit the page.